# Coding Help (HTTP Error 500)

Tags: php, html

So let's say i have this code.txt file :

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</body
<html>
```

And whenever i want to add a page , i just create a file named page.php :

```
<?php
$title="page title";
$content="Page content coded in html";

require 'code.txt';
?>
```

The page.php file returns into a HTTP Error 500 on the browser , whenever i add HTML elements like hyperlinks on the $content string . How do i fix this ?

Comment: By fixing your code. Either enable error reporting in PHP or read your error log from Apache.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to [**do your homework**](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3AStackoverflow.com+php+HTTP+Error+500). Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Won't apache not process file extensions unless they have a handler attached in the apache config?

Comment: @PolishPrince Please don't overuse pro-forma comments. It doesn't apply in this case. I don't think there is any "research" possible for such a specific occasion of a 500 error with hyperlinks in a required .txt file.

Comment: @Antony Clearly the OP **didn't** do any research. *"We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise"*. Perhaps you should read the FAQ?

Comment: @PolishPrince Unless a so-called research in the context of the problem would likely yield viable solutions, it is enough if the OP actually tried something and identified a pattern in his problem ("whenever i add HTML elements like hyperlinks on the $content string").

Comment: Does the page return something if you just load `codes.txt` from the browser? Maybe the server does not handle any files? Maybe php is down? Maybe PHP is denied from www files?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a `.txt` file extension for PHP/HTML. Use an extension PHP will recognize like `.php` or `.inc`.

Comment: It doesnt matter in this usage. require/include will read and parse any file extension you give it

Comment: I have tried using code.php extension and it still doesnt work